# DirectoryInfo only finds path from localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DirectoryInfo variable declared as followed:

```
DirectoryInfo rootDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\server01\Shared\Saved Stuff\");
```

The following code returns true when I run my website from localhost but false when I publish it and upload it.

```
bool doesItExist = rootDirectory.Exists;
```

I do not believe (in fact I am convinced) this is a security permissions issue since I gave the entity "Everyone" full access to the destination folder.  Anyone have a clue as to why this may be happening and only exclusively on live side?  FYI, when I remote desktop to the server01 and type in the above path, I can access it without any problems, just as well as I can from a local machine.

Comment: @Convinced - Note that "Everyone" doesn't include "Anonymous" - [more info here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772745.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using windows authentication for your site...

Most likely you are running into "NTLM one-hop" - credentials passed to server from other machine can't be reused to access third machine and as result \server01\shared is being accessed by non-authenticated user.

To confirm - try to use browser on the server where you deployed the code to navigate to the page that uses this code.

Comment: thanks for this answer! can you help me with this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509022/publishing-asp-net-application-to-the-internet

Comment: That's the strange part.  I can easily navigate from the machine I coded from to the machine, even folder, that hosts the actual website. I frankly don't believe there should even be a reason for this behavior but alas there it is.  You seemed to have helped somene with your answer and so you will get a point for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DirectoryInfo rootDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"\\server01\Shared\Saved Stuff\"));
```

Comment: thank you! was wondering if you can help with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509022/publishing-asp-net-application-to-the-internet#comment12043101_9509022

Comment: No that unfortunately returns an incorrect path of C:\inetpub\wwwroot\server01\Shared\Saved Stuff\