# publishing asp.net application to the internet

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

i have  a web app that runs locally on our network. the way users access it is by going to `myserver:80/site/default.aspx`

i reconfigured the settings to display the website to the internet.

the way i am accessing it now is:

```
ipaddress/site/default.aspx
```

and getting the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /site/default.aspx
```

so it seems as if it does see the site, but the site does not want to grant access?

what am i doing wrong?

**edit** if the consensus is that it doesnt actually see the webpage. then again i would like to know what i am doing wrong

Comment: 404 means it *doesn't* see the site.  If it sees it but wasn't granting access, it would likely be error 403, with a more specific message.

Comment: @CptSupermrkt i dont think so. if i put any other nonexistent file like default.aaa then i would get 404 and it wouldnt be an asp.net message

Comment: He means that you said you are accessing the site with "ipaddress/site/default.aspx", yet the error message says: "Requested URL: /sdwh/default.aspx"  There's a typo there.  "sdwh" vs. "site"

Comment: @CptSupermrkt thank you for the interpretation i updated

Comment: ...and you are getting a 404.  I mean I've seen some pretty bizarre and unexplained stuff, so it's not outside the real of possibility that something is actually wrong with permissions, but I know from wrestling my way through the membership systems that if there is a problem with permissions, the error explicitly "403 Forbidden".  Best way to try would be to actually try putting some garbage in like you said, "default.aaa," something that clearly doesn't exist.  I'm betting it will give you the exact same error as you're getting now.

Comment: What page is served when you navigate to http://ipaddress? It sounds like you don't have your IIS configured correctly.

Comment: @jfmags you're probably right. when i just go to ipaddress then i get Under Construction The site you are trying to view does not currently have a default page. It may be in the process of being upgraded and configured.

Comment: @CptSupermrkt wanted to confirm that default.aaa produces THE PAGE CANNOT BE FOUND, whereas default.aspx produces the RESOURCE CANNOT BE FOUND (asp.net error) as opposed to general browser error

Comment: @jfmags any idea which settings need to be adjusted ? :)

Comment: which version of IIS are you using?

Comment: @jfmags i just found it it was 6.0. im sorry to bother you again but can you please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the host header bindings in IIS for your website.

If you are really on IIS 5.1 (which ONLY shipped with Windows XP Pro) then do the following:

1. Open your IIS Manager (go to start > run > inetmgr).
2. Expand the computer name.
3. Expand websites.
4. Right click on the site name
5. Go to the Website tab
6. Click on the Advanced button
7. In the "multiple identities for this web site" click the Add button
8. Set the IP address.  Leave the Host Header Value *blank*
9. Click Ok

At this point there should be 2 identities listed.  One that maps the DNS name to the IP address and another that only has the IP address.

IF for some reason it warns you about duplicate bindings, go to the other sites and remove any that tie the IP address to a blank host header.  Then come back to this site and set up the blank configuration.

Comment: chris its actually version 6.0!! and i do not see where i can do this

Comment: @I__: you might want to start here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732269.aspx

Comment: its actually server 2003 r2., not vista

Comment: chris thank you again but this setup is not for internet, its for intranet. that intranet part already works for me, im just having trouble broadcasting to internet

Comment: chriis my gut feeling is that there's someting blocking the port. windows firewall is not running. what else do you think it might be? i checked the log for iis and it doesnt have an http error, just shows that some ip tried to get to my page

Comment: @I__: see update.  It is not a firewall thing because you are getting the server error in application page and/or the default website page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8461/discussion-between-i-and-chris-lively)

Answer (score 1):

When moving from Visual Studio's built-in web server to IIS, often you need to simply remove the top level directory form the URL:

```
ipaddress/default.aspx
```

or simply

```
ipaddress
```

if default.aspx really is a default.

Comment: thanks so much.  when i just go to the IP i get Under Construction


The site you are trying to view does not currently have a default page. It may be in the process of being upgraded and configured.

Comment: when i go to the IP/default.aspx i am getting Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Comment: It sounds like IIS isn't configured for your new site yet. So, you're getting the default website instead. See config instructions beginning at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178477.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

In normal case if you are hosting your site in IIS and if you are having your IP fix you can also browse your website through your local ip in your network by address by keeping your 'ipaddress' in place of 'localhost'. Now if you wants to access it from your global ip you need to add binding to the IIS and then it will respond to all the requests.

So in your particular case you need to add binding with your IP (check it from whatismyip.com). Go to IIS -> Sites -> Default Web Site. On right hand side column you will get bindings. Add new binding in it.

Comment: asif thank you so much! i am using version 6.0 can you please tell me how i would do this here