# Dynamically accessing array variables from Code Behind in ASPX

Tags: asp.net, arrays, code-behind

Due to the nature of the current file system I am working with I have to dynamically access array variables in ASPX page from the code-behind page. I got it to the point where I am able to pull any one explicitly stated variable, but cannot seem to pull them dynamically.

Code Behind:

```
public partial class some_class : System.Web.UI.Page {
    public string[] array123 = new string[100];

    ....
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       someFunction();
    }

    protected void someFunction() {
       int i = 1;
       _TempDt = Locator._New_Locator(value)

       foreach (DataRow _TempDR in _TempDt.Rows) {
          array123[i] = Server.UrlEncode(address);
          i++;
       }
    }
}
```

ASPX:

```
....
<asp:Repeater ID="DataList" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <label onClick="javascript:popup('page.aspx?key=<%= array123[1] %>')">Get link</label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This only pulls the stated (2nd) value in the array and it needs to be dynamic with the repeater.

Thanks.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking here. Do you want to get the value of the array at the position of the repeater index? ie: item n of the repeater will display item n of the array?

Comment: Shai Cohen, yes, that is exactly what I am trying to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
<p><%# array123[Container.ItemIndex] %></p>
```

Comment: perhaps you can help wiht this one now! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509022/publishing-asp-net-application-to-the-internet

Comment: jfmags,
this is actually what I tried but it throws a compilation error
"CS0103: The name 'Container' does not exist in the current context"

i actually edited the ASPX page code above to reflect what it actually looks like (i know its ugly, but this is what i have to work with)

Comment: you were probably missing the #

Comment: sorry - it should be this <p><%# array123[Container.ItemIndex] %></p>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

< %#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex", "")%>