# Session lost while migrating of ASP.NET 2.0 Applications to IIS 7.5 on Big I/p load balancing environment. Works fine in Windows Server 2000 and 2003

Tags: asp.net

I have moved my applications from windows 2000 to 2008. I could setup all .net  applications successfully in IIS 7.5. I have web famr setup with load balancing on two servers through Big I/p. When I access the applications I find the session is becoming null and lost. It is sporadic and not happening all the time. Iam using inproc session state. I have googled and tried out lot of lot of options like 
- setting IIS->ASP-> Session-> Generate New Session ID to false;
and some other configuration  changes.

Iam using apppool as .net 2.0 with integrate Mode. I have even set enable 32 bit applications = true also.

I have already configured Sessiontimeout="240" in my web.config.

Some times if I refresh the web page it is working fine and getting the session populated.
Iam facing the issue when Iam redirecting to some other page and session value is becoming null during that page load.

I want to access the apps only in Inproc State. Kindly please suggest correct configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Your session is being lost as you bounce onto different machines in the farm. You'll need to make sure you have the same machine key, or use a different technique for storing sessions (state server or sql server)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx#paght000007_webfarmdeploymentconsiderations

And another article:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/gopenath/Page107182007032219AM/Page1.aspx

Comment: thank you! was wondering if you can help with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509022/publishing-asp-net-application-to-the-internet#comment12043101_9509022

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue because the site's app pool in IIS7 had a number of max worker processes greater than 1 (under the app pool's advanced settings). So the site was running as a 'web garden', and the session was being lost between processes.

For my fix, I changed the max number of worker processes to 1, but there are a few resolutions.

This link gives more info on web gardens (albeit it IIS6) http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/02/on-web-gardens-aspnet-and-iis-60/