# Classic ASP Windows server 2008 IIS 7.5, 64 bit

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

We have a classic ASP application running on IIS 6, windows 2003, 32 bit. We need to migrate this to IIS 7.5, Windows server 2008, 64 bit server. While doing this, we are getting an error as below -

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14'
>
> [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
>
> /abcproj/getresult.asp, line 67

in line 67 of getresult.asp, the code is opening a connection (to Oracle) with a search query. This is a query to get the list of users from our DB.

We have followed all the steps for ASP client installation on IIS 7.5. We have done all the configurations required for running ASP client on IIS 7.5. We have google'd a lot to find the cause and fix for this error with no success. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

RJ

Comment: Have you installed the 32-bit oracle driver, and not the 64-bit driver? You'll need to use the odbccad32.exe program in the C\:Windows\sysWOW64 folder to see what 32-bit drivers are installed, and not the one in c:\Windows\system32 (that one shows only 64-bit drivers). Also, have you enabled 32-bit support in the application pool in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some other thing has failed and the sql isn't being passed all the correct parameters.  First thing I would do is make sure that the sql statement is valid by isolating the search query that is actually being run and then trying to manually run it on the sql server.

Comment: @ Rico, we have installed Oracle 11g 32 bit client using C\:Windows\sysWOW64.  On further investigation, we have found that the sql statement is not getting retained in the session. As mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509271/session-lost-while-migrating-of-asp-net-2-0-applications-to-iis-7-5-on-big-i-p-l  we have verified that the max worker processes attribute is set as 1, but it did not solve the issue. Any suggestions / pointers will be of immense help.   Thanks much