# EF will only let me choose SQL Server CE 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I have a Visual Studio solution with two projects: `MyApp.MvcUI` and `MyApp.Domain` (class library).

`MyApp.MvcUI` contains my SQL Server CE 4 database.

`MyApp.Domain` is supposed to contain the Entity Framework EDMX file, but if I add it there I don't have the option to use SQL Server CE 4, only 3.5.

http://www.codetunnel.com/content/images/sqlce35only.jpg

If I add the EDMX in the `MvcUI` project then I am able to choose SQL Server CE 4.

Question

1. How can I put my Entity Framework content into the `MyApp.Domain` project and use a SQL Server CE 4 database that lives in the `MyApp.MvcUI` project?
2. Once I solved that problem, what will the data source portion of my connection string in `App.Config` look like? I know the web project's connection string will simply look like this:

   ```
   Data Source=|DataDirectory|\CE4DB.sdf
   ```

   but what will that look like in `App.Config` in the `MyApp.Domain` project? Will it be an absolute path like

   ```
   C:\Code\MyProject\MyApp.MvcUI\App_Data\CE4DB.sdf
   ```

If so, is there a way to make that a relative path so when people pull the project down from source control it will still work without path corrections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the suggestions here. My EF was already at the latest version (4.3 as of this post) but I did install SQL Server CE through nuget as well as EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact which says "Allows SQL Server Compact 4.0 to be used with Entity Framework." Still no option to use CE 4 in the wizard when trying to update the EDMX model from database. If this is all done in the MVC project then I do have the option to use CE 4 in the dialogue box pictured in my question.

I did get it to work though. I simply used a connection string like the one it generates when I put the EDMX in the MVC project.

```
<add name="EntityContainer" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|
                                res://*/Model1.ssdl|
                                res://*/Model1.msl;
                       provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;
       provider connection string=&quot;
         Data Source=..\MyApp.MvcUI\App_Data\CE4DB.sdf&quot;"
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I was then able to get the EF designer to read from the database. As a bonus the data source path is relative :D so other developers pulling down a fresh copy of the project from source control will also be able to use the EF designer straight away without tweaking it. I'm planning to switch to code-first EF soon but I wanted to get this all working with the EDMX first since that's what I know how to do currently.

Obviously at runtime the connection string in MyApp.Domain does not matter because it reads from the active project's config file. In this case Web.Config for the MvcUI project. In which the connection string is even easier since the path is simplified.

```
<add name="EntityContainer"
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|
                                res://*/Model1.ssdl|
                                res://*/Model1.msl;
                       provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;
       provider connection string=&quot;
         Data Source=|DataDirectory|\CE4DB.sdf&quot;"
       providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: I had the same problem. I tried adding the connection string to my app.config, but when adding the EF model, I couldn't select the connection string from the app.config file. So I had to add the EF model and create a new connection string to my local SQL server express and when asked which objects to map, I selected none. So I got an empty EF model and it saved the connection string to my app.config. Then I just changed the connection string in the app.config to point to my CE database, opened the EF designer and updated from the database, and voilá! :-)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have to do the following (what I did for mine)

1. Install EF 4.1
2. Install SQL Server CE 4.0

Comment: thank you! was wondering if you can help with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509022/publishing-asp-net-application-to-the-internet#comment12043101_9509022

Comment: You got this to work in a class library? I have done that and more and the wizard still shows what is pictured in my question.

Comment: Did you install the 4.0 runtime for CE?

Answer (score 3):

The 4.0 EDMX wizard only works for Web projects, as you have noticed. You can use my SQL Server Compact Toolbox add-in to create and 4.0 EDMX in any project type.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomment using NuGet to download EF, SQL Server CE 4.0, and all the needed dependencies, and automatically add them to your projects.

This will also set up the needed provider in your app config, in case this is missing.

If you're not familiar with NuGet, you can start by right-clicking your project in the solution explorer window, and choosing "Add Library Reference". (Maybe that's not the accurate name, but it's easy to find).

Comment: I do use nuget and I have already obtained EF 4.3 with it. I did not know they had Sql Server Compact. Thank you. One question though, do I install that in the Domain (class library) project or in the web project?

Comment: It would seem adding that to the class library did not help. The wizard still doesn't let me choose CE 4 like it does when I put the EDMX in the web project. Works in one project not the other. So weird.

Nevertheless, I did get it to work. I will post it as an answer.